# How to get url value from Property of a page in IE.

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, webdriver

I am trying to automate a system having static url concept in IE browser.
But still we can see the exact url by simply visiting properties menu after doing rigth click.[image]

I am looking for the url visible in the attached picture.
driver.getcurrenturl() is not giving what I want. its simply printing url from url tab.

Comment: Are you sure the stuff that's visible really has a different URL? It might all be javascript which changes the DOM but it won't change the URL...

Comment: yes its happening in my project. I have some limitations thats why cant give you people code or screen short.

Comment: Hi, you can use GPEdit.msc (Group policy editor) to place restrictions on which menus are visible on a 'static site concept' burlesque IE browser. The common design pattern for single site kiosk browsers is to use a command line switch in a desktop shortcut (.lnk file). Kiosk mode IE does not have any UI elements and is suited for 'single site' kiosk applications for web browsers.